# (Handsontable) - hot.setCellMeta doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

In the page that contains my Handsontable's table I've defined a class:

```
.redCell {
    background: "#FF0000";
 }
```

Then in the source code I call the "**setCellMeta()**" method:

```
hot.setCellMeta(row, column, 'className', 'redCell');
hot.render();
```

But unfortunately cells are not being colored in red.

By using

```
hot.getCell(row,column).style.background = "#FF0000";
```

everything works fine, but each time the table is re-rendered (i.e. dragging cells), cells lost their color.